# Error when trying to use decimal.js with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, decimal.js

I am trying to use decimal.js in my typescript project. But when I try to execute the below example I get the following error: `Cannot assign to read only property 'constructor' of object '[object Object]`

```
import { Decimal } from "decimal.js";

Decimal.set({ rounding: 5 });
Decimal.set({ modulo: Decimal.ROUND_FLOOR });
Decimal.set({ crypto: true });
Decimal.set({ precision: 1e+4 });
Decimal.set({ toExpPos: 1000 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a single call to the `Decimal.set` function?

You could try printing in the console between calls to see which one is causing the problem. However, the set method can take all parameters at once. Maybe the method has an asynchronous operation.

Try this way:

```
Decimal.set({
   rounding: 5,
   mod: Decimal.ROUND_FLOOR,
   crypto: true,
   accuracy: 1e+4,
   toExpPos: 1000,
});
```

Comment: I did try this way as well, and also setting it individually and it throws this error: Cannot assign to read only property 'constructor' of object '[object Object]'